# How send parameter to a url without using form in php?

Tags: php

dear all,
I need to send parameters to a URL without using form in php and get value from that page.We can easily send parameters using form like this:

```
<html>
    <form action="http://..../abc.php" method="get">
    <input name="id" type="text" />
    <input name="name" type="text"/>
    <input  type="submit" value="press" />
    </form>
</html>
```

But i already have value like this

```
     <?php 
       $id="123";
       $name="blahblah";
      ?>
```

Now i need to send values to http://..../abc.php without using form.when the 2 value send to abc.php link then it's show a value **OK**.Now i have to collect the "OK" msg from abc.php and print on my current page.
i need to auto execute the code.when user enter into the page those value automatically send to a the url.So i can't use form or href. because form and href need extra one click.

Is their any kind heart who can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You've been suggested almost all possibilities (clickable link, load page from server, HTTP redirect, AJAX...). You should clarify your exact needs and why none of the solutions are suitable.

Answer (score 8):

You can pass values via GET using a hyperlink:

```
<a href='abc.php?id=123&name=blahblah' />
```

`print_r($_GET)` would then give you the values, or you can use `$_GET['id']` etc in `abc.php`

Other approaches, depending on your needs, include using AJAX to POST/GET the request asynchronously, or using include/require to pull in abc.php if it only includes specific functioanlity.eg:

```
   $id="123";
   $name="blahblah";
   require('abc.php');
```

Comment: Href is not suitable.because i need to send it directly when the code execute.thx any other solution?

Comment: @JanHančič You haven't given an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$id="123";
$name="blahblah";
echo "<a href = 'http://foo.com/abc.php?id=$id&name=$name'> link </a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$base = 'http://example.com/abc.php';
$id="123";
$name="blahblah";

$data = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'name' => $name,
);

$url = $base . '?' . http_build_query($data);

header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but when i send two value to abc.php then it show OK.Now i need to print OK message to my current page.That's why i can't redirect my page.

Comment: @riad, not with the information currently available, I'm afraid. Are you sure that none of the solutions provided solve your problem?